# DatagridView no se "dibuja" al ejecutar mi aplicación si no paso el ratón por encima o muevo el scroll

Tags: c#, datagrid

tengo un problema curioso con mi datagridview, y es que despues de actualizar mi VS 2017, al ejecutar mi aplicación, no me muestra los datos en el dgv. Pero en cuanto muevo el scroll vertical, comienzan a a aparecer poco a poco. No es un problema de código, pues he puesto un segundo dgv de prueba que carga la misma table y resulta que el primer dgv ahora si aparece con todos los datos cargados y el dgv de prueba es el que no los carga hasta que muevo el scroll o pulso sobre una cabecera de columna.

Este es el código con el que cargo el dgv en el Load del formulario:

```
dgvEmpleados.DataSource = negocio.MostrarTodoEmpleados();
dgvEmpleados.MultiSelect = false;
```

Y en esta imagen ven como aparece el dgv. Luego si muevo el scroll o minimizo y luego maximizo la ventana, ya muestra los 50 registros que tiene.

Agradecería cualquier pista que puedan darme, pues no es un problema de código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto esta imagen más reveladora de lo que me ocurre con el dgv. Al ir haciendo click en diferentes partes de mi dgv, me van apareciendo los datos sólo donde he hecho click.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, si hago click en la cabecera de alguna de las columnas o muevo el scroll del ratón, ya me aparecen todos los datos dibujados en el dgv. La verdad es que no lo entiendo y estas son las cosas que me desesperan de la programación, pues llevo semanas intentando solucionarlo y no hay manera.

Lo he intentado poniendo otro dgv llamado dgvPrueba junto a mi dgvEmpleados y resulta que así si me salen bien los datos del dgvEmpleados y ahora me salen mal "dibujados" los datos del dtvPrueba..... Es una locura.

Esto es lo que he estado probando:

private void frmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

```
            dgvEmpleados.DataSource = negocio.MostrarTodoEmpleados();
            dgvPrueba.DataSource = negocio.MostrarTodoEmpleados();

            //dgvPrueba.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            //dgvPrueba.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            //dgvPrueba.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;


            //dgvEmpleados.CurrentCell = null;
            //dgvPrueba.CurrentCell = null;
            //intenté usar estos dos metodos del grid para forzar el repintado del control, pero no funcionó.
            //dgvEmpleados.Update();
            //dgvEmpleados.Refresh();

            ///He tenido que añadir este codigo porque no me dibujaba las filas del DGV si no pasaba el ratón por encima...¿?KK
            ///añadi incluso otro DGV de prueba y entonces si me aparecían las filas del DGV principal y no las de el nuevo DGV. 
            ///Algo RARÍSIMO.
            //dgvEmpleados.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None; //Quita los bordes de celdas.
            //dgvEmpleados.CurrentCell = dgvEmpleados[1, (dgvEmpleados.Rows.Count)-1];
            //dgvEmpleados.CurrentCell = dgvEmpleados.Rows[0].Cells[1];
            //dgvEmpleados.CurrentCell = dgvEmpleados[1, 1];

            dgvEmpleados.MultiSelect = false;
            dgvVacaciones.MultiSelect = false;
            dtpFechaIni.Value = DateTime.Now;
            dtpFechaFin.Value = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            txtAgno.Text = Convert.ToString(today.Year);
            lblFechaHoy.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
            PonerCabecerasDgvEmpleados();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu problema esta relacionado con el repintado del grid una vez cargada la información.
`dgvEmpleados.DataSource = negocio.MostrarTodoEmpleados();
dgvEmpleados.MultiSelect = false;
//intenta usar estos dos metodos del grid para forzar el repintado del control.
dgvEmpleados.update()
dgvEmpleados.Refresh()`

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación. La he probado pero sigue exactamente igual. Yo estoy convencido que no es un problema de código, pues cuando cree el segundo dgv de prueba, el dgv inicial funcionó correctamente y el de prueba no se dibujaba correctamente.

Comment: Para que puedan enteder lo que le ocurre a mi dgv (DataGridView) les muestro esta imagen que es más reveladora que la anterior.